# MySQL get specific number from order of query result

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I have a table called **users**, in the users table there is a column called **rating**. Since I am creating a leaderboard, I order the top 100 users by rating. Each ranking of the leaderboard is simply displayed by a code like this

```
<% let i = 0;
for(const row of users) { %>
 <%= i; %>. <%= row.username; %>
<% } %>
```

Then the leaderboard gets displayed simply like this

```
1. John
2. Doe
3. Mike
4. Peter
....
....
```

Now I also want to  show the specific rank of  the player viewing the page. Since I have over 5,000 registered accounts, I want to display something like this:

```
Your leaderboard placing:
2854. Erik
```

But I have to get the rank for Erik that is 2854 without having to loop trough the whole users table in order to access that number. How do I do this efficiently?

Comment: a query to find the rank of erik ?

Comment: Correct. Or any user in particular

Comment: please refer this [link ] (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-where-clause.htm)

Comment: Haha, that is not the problem. I want to get the rank of the player, and the rank is determined by where they are placed when select the users and order them by "rating". Therefore I can't just pick the rank out.

Comment: can you pls post sample data? and more info on logic to find the rank?

Comment: For a given player count tne number of players with a lower rating. count +1 is the rank of the player.

Comment: Look at the code in the question, the rank is determined by just a simple for loop where I have a variable "i" which increases by 1 every loop. The variable "i" is thas is displayed before the name (the rank), so 4. Peter = i + username. I just need to get the rank instantly without having to loop trough my whole users table because that contains above 5000 users.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, there is `RANK()` operation that calculates the ranking of rows using `ORDER BY`. For example :

```
SELECT
    username, rating,
    RANK() OVER (
        ORDER BY rating
    ) rank
FROM
    leaderboard;
```

The output will have 3 columns: username, rating, and rank. The rank columns is the ranking calculate from `rating`

You can find more information from these links :

- https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-rank-function/
- https://www.educba.com/mysql-rank/

--- EDIT ---

To get the rank of a specific user, I think we will run the WHERE clause on the ranking table.

```
WITH ranking AS 

(SELECT
    username, rating,
    RANK() OVER (
        ORDER BY rating
    ) rank
FROM
    leaderboard;
)

SELECT * FROM ranking WHERE username = "Erik"
```

Comment: This was just kind of what I was looking for, how do I get the rank for a specific player though? I tried this ```SELECT
    username, rating,
    RANK() OVER (
        ORDER BY rating DESC
    ) rank
FROM
    users WHERE username = 'Erik';``` but then the rank is always 1.

Comment: I think the WHERE clause that limit the number of row to only 1, and the RANK is calculed after that.

Comment: Probably yes, do you know of any other way to get the result I am wishing for?

Comment: I think we need to calcul the ranking before applying the filter. I edited my answer.

Comment: "Unrecognized statement type. (near "WITH" at position 0)" I get this error?

Comment: maybe checking the mysql manual about the syntax ? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html. I don't have any tools to run it though.. sorry.

Comment: I see. Well the problem is that according to the manual it seems correct already. I'll keep looking.